# Error in JSON Watson Conversation

Tags: json, watson-conversation

I am trying to set the entity value to null to exit the loop when user enter no but getting this error.
" Your changes can not be saved because of the errors below:
root: Response can only contain properties: output,context,actions "
I tried to set the value null and empty string as well but none of them worked.
Please find the attachment of the error.

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You get that error, because you have unrecognized property `conditions`,
only `output`, `context` and `actions` properties are allowed in JSON response.

I am not familiar with Slots functionality, but Conversation API agrees with me that there is no such property in response.

Delete `"conditions": "#no",` line to fix the error.

Comment: if i delete the "conditions: "#no", then on what basis slot will set the value of entity to null

Comment: I tried as you suggested but it isn't exiting the loop

Comment: @RehmanKhan I gave you an answer how to fix the error - conditions are not supposed to be defined there. If you want to ask how to set exit condition, it is better to ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

After getting my hands dirty, I figured out. Need to set the context variable = "", and select the option "skip the slot" when it detects the value "no" or any value you want to exit the loop (it could rather be intent or an entity).